# GearVRf - SceneObject not visible with GVSphere Image

Tags: android, gear-vr

I am trying to show a dot/pointer on `GVRSphereSceneObject` in `GearVR`. But, only the `GVRSphereSceneObject` is showing where as scene object hides once the texture image becomes visible. If I add both sphere and object using `addSceneObject`, then image is shown on one side and rest of view is blacked out.

I couldn't find any issue regarding this and tried samples also. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for adding object over sphere.

```
    Future<GVRTexture> texture = gvrContext.loadFutureTexture(new GVRAndroidResource(gvrContext, R.raw.pano));

    GVRMaterial material = new GVRMaterial(gvrContext);
    material.setMainTexture(texture);

    boom = new GVRSphereSceneObject(gvrContext, 18, 36, false, material);

    Pointer = new GVRSceneObject(gvrContext,
            new FutureWrapper<>(gvrContext.createQuad(0.05f, 0.05f)),
            gvrContext.loadFutureTexture(new GVRAndroidResource(this.gvrContext, R.drawable.target)));
    Pointer.getRenderData().getMaterial().setColor(Colors.RED[0], Colors.RED[1], Colors.RED[2]);

    Pointer.getTransform().setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    Pointer.setName("Pointer");
    boom.addChildObject(Pointer);
    scene.addSceneObject(boom);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling with this. Please have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/issues/2021).

> ```
> Pointer.getRenderData().setDepthTest(false);
> Pointer.getRenderData().setRenderingOrder(SXRRenderData.SXRRenderingOrder.OVERLAY);
> ```